# NSInvalidArgumentException: Illegal attempt to establish a relationship between objects in different contexts

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I have an app based on the CoreDataBooks example that uses an `addingManagedObjectContext` to add an `Ingredient` to a `Cocktail` in order to undo the entire add. The `CocktailsDetailViewController` in turn calls a `BrandPickerViewController` to (optionally) set a brand name for a given ingredient. `Cocktail`, `Ingredient` and `Brand` are all `NSManagedObjects`. `Cocktail` requires at least one `Ingredient` (`baseLiquor`) to be set, so I create it when the `Cocktail` is created.

If I add the `Cocktail` in `CocktailsAddViewController : CocktailsDetailViewController` (merging into the Cocktail managed object context on save) without setting `baseLiquor.brand`, then it works to set the `Brand` from a picker (also stored in the Cocktails managed context) later from the `CocktailsDetailViewController`.

However, if I try to set `baseLiquor.brand` in `CocktailsAddViewController`, I get:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   'Illegal attempt to establish a
>   relationship 'brand' between objects
>   in different contexts'

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136388/passing-objects-between-managed-object-contexts) I understand that the issue is that `Brand` is stored in the app's `managedObjectContext` and the newly added `Ingredient` and `Cocktail` are stored in `addingManagedObjectContext`, and that passing the `ObjectID` instead would avoid the crash.

What I don't get is how to implement the picker generically so that all of the Ingredients (`baseLiquor`, `mixer`, `garnish`, etc.) can be set during the add, as well as one-by-one from the `CocktailsDetailViewController` after the `Cocktail` has been created. In other words, following the CoreDataBooks example, where and when would the `ObjectID` be turned into the `NSManagedObject` from the parent MOC in both add and edit cases? -IPD

**UPDATE** - Here's the add method:

```
- (IBAction)addCocktail:(id)sender {

    CocktailsAddViewController *addViewController = [[CocktailsAddViewController alloc] init];
    addViewController.title = @"Add Cocktail";
    addViewController.delegate = self;

    // Create a new managed object context for the new book -- set its persistent store coordinator to the same as that from the fetched results controller's context.
    NSManagedObjectContext *addingContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    self.addingManagedObjectContext = addingContext;
    [addingContext release];

    [addingManagedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:[[fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext] persistentStoreCoordinator]];

    Cocktail *newCocktail = (Cocktail *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Cocktail" inManagedObjectContext:self.addingManagedObjectContext];
    newCocktail.baseLiquor = (Ingredient *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Ingredient" inManagedObjectContext:self.addingManagedObjectContext];
    newCocktail.mixer = (Ingredient *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Ingredient" inManagedObjectContext:self.addingManagedObjectContext];
    newCocktail.volume = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
    addViewController.cocktail = newCocktail;

    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:addViewController];

    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];

    [addViewController release];
    [navController release];

}
```

and here's the site of the crash in the `Brand` picker (this `NSFetchedResultsController` is backed by the app delegate's managed object context:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

    if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(pickerViewController:didFinishWithBrand:forKeyPath:)]) 
    {
        [delegate pickerViewController:self 
               didFinishWithBrand:(Brand *)[fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath] 
                            forKeyPath:keyPath]; // 'keyPath' is @"baseLiquor.brand" in the crash
    }
}
```

and finally the delegate implementation:

```
- (void)pickerViewController:(IngredientsPickerViewController *)pickerViewController
          didFinishWithBrand:(Brand *)baseEntity
                  forKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
{

    // set entity
    [cocktail setValue:ingredient forKeyPath:keyPath];  

    // Save the changes.
    NSError *error;
    if (![cocktail.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        // Update to handle the error appropriately.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        exit(-1);  // Fail
    }

    // dismiss picker
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]
}
```

**EVEN MORE**

I'm making progess based on Marcus' suggestions -- I mapped the `addingManagedObjectContexts` to the parent managedObjectContext and wrapped everything in `begin/endUndoGrouping` to handle cancel vs. save.

However, the object to be created is in an `NSFetchedResultsController`, so when the user hits the "+" button to add the `Cocktail`, the (possibly-to-be-undone) entity briefly appears in the table view as the modal add view controller is presented. The MDN example is Mac-based so it doesn't touch on this UI behavior. What can I do to avoid this?

Comment: Why do you have two managed object context? That rarely used and is fairly high level stuff. Nothing I see in your description of your problem space seems to require separate context.

Comment: I don't anymore, but that is what is used in the Apple CoreDataBooks example to allow intermediate undos -- undo editing, undo the edit, undo (never do) the add.

With a single context and undo grouping I'm still struggling to get the intermediate undo back (undo an entire field edit.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you are creating two different Core Data stacks (`NSManagedObjectContext`, `NSManagedObjectModel`, and `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`).  What you want to do from the example is just create two `NSManagedObjectContext` instances pointing at the same `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`.  That will resolve this issue.

Think of the `NSManagedObjectContext` as a scratch pad.  You can have as many as you want and if you throw it away before saving it, the data contained within it is gone. But they all save to the same place.

### update

The CoreDataBooks is unfortunately a really terrible example. However, for your issue, I would suggest *removing* the creation of the additional context and see if the error occurs. Based on the code you posted and I assume the code you copied directly from Apple's example, the double context, while virtually useless, should work fine.  Therefore I suspect there is something else at play.

Try using a single context and see if the issue persists. You may have some other interesting but subtle error that is giving you this error; perhaps a overrelease somewhere or something along those lines.  But the first step is to remove the double context and see what happens.

### update 2

If it is crashing even with a single MOC then your issue has nothing to do with the contexts.  What is the error you are getting with a single MOC? When we solve that, then we will solve your entire issue.

As for a better solution, use `NSUndoManager` instead.  That is what it is designed for.  Apple **REALLY** should not be recommending multiple MOCs in their example.

I answered a question on here recently about using the `NSUndoManager` with Core Data but you can also look at some of my articles on the MDN for an example.

Comment: Don't think that's it -- both `managedObjectContext` and `addingManagedObjectContext` are set to the same `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` as in the SDK example.

Comment: The error you posted is caused by one situation; two `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` instances.  Perhaps if you shared your code that builds the contexts it would help to show what you are doing.

Comment: Still stumped. There is only one `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` (alloced and owned by the app delegate), a master `NSManagedObjectContext` (alloced and owned by the app delegate) and a couple `addingManagedObjectContexts` that are alloced in a `NSFetchedResultsController` and inited with the app delegate's `persistentStoreCoordinator`. The crash comes when a `Brand` already saved in the master MOC is assigned to a new `Ingredient` created in the adding MOC but not yet saved to the master. Which of the MOC building calls do you want to see?

Comment: The creation of the secondary Contexts would be helpful

Comment: Saw your update -- I already tried that after your first answer and it crashed harder (something to do with the interaction of the `NSNotificationCenter` and the fetched results controller inherited from Apple's example.)

Can you recommend an alternate sample/tutorial to CoreDataBooks that preserves the undo-an-entire-add behavior?

Comment: +1 especially because I can't believe this answer didn't get any votes before.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you definitely don't want to cross context boundaries when setting relationships between objects; they both need to be in the same NSManagedObjectContext. In the old EOF, there were APIs for faulting objects into different contexts, but doesn't look like CoreData has an equivalent.